# How to move the contents in this HTML

Tags: css

I am new to CSS so please if this is a easy one .

Please look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gn8fy3rc/3/

I wanted to move the text moneycontrol ,beside time and the text content to be displayed opposite the image .

Some part of my code

```
<div class="column-a">
   <section class="widget">
      <h4 class="widget-title">Latest News</h4>
      <div id="divRss">
         <ul class="feedEkList">
            <li>
               <div class="itemTitle"><a href="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/results-boardroom/attrition-to-peak-out-normalise-around-18-20-cyient_3627581.html" target="_blank">Attrition to peak out, normalise around 18-20%: Cyient</a></div>
               <div class="itemDate">
                  10/16/2015, 12:24 PM
                  <div class="Source">moneycontrol</div>
                  <div class="itemContent"><img src="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2015/c/Cyient_200.jpg" alt="Ajay Aggarwal" title="Ajay Aggarwal" border="0" width="75" height="75" hspace="5"> Seventy percent of the margin improvement basically came from rupee depreciation and rest from operational efficiencies and high margin jobs, said Ajay Aggarwal, Senior VP  CFO, Cyient.</div>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <div class="itemTitle"><a href="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/results-boardroom/expect-20-topline-growthfy16-sintex-industries_3626821.html" target="_blank">Expect 20% topline growth in FY16: Sintex Industries</a></div>
               <div class="itemDate">
                  10/16/2015, 11:11 AM
                  <div class="Source">moneycontrol</div>
                  <div class="itemContent"><img src="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2015/s/samir-joshipura-200.jpg" alt="Samir Joshipura" title="Samir Joshipura" border="0" width="75" height="75" hspace="5"> Samir Joshipura Group CEO, Sintex is confident of meeting the guidance of 20 percent topline growth in FY16 and margin growth between 50-100 basis points.</div>
               </div>
            </li>

         </ul>
      </div>
   </section>

   <!--widget-->
</div>
```

Could you please let em know how to do this

Comment: Why **tag** `jquery` if it is a `CSS` issue?

Comment: you should have a look at the following techniques: inline-block, floating, flex-box. they all do the same, with different approaches.

Comment: **[Is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gn8fy3rc/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution:

```
.itemContent { display: flex; }
.itemContent > img { min-width: 75px; }
.itemDate > .Source { display: inline-block; }
```

(since thats what you tagged the question with..)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/po1a04mx/)

Answer (score -1):

Make date and source a tag be at the same level, choose an inline element instead of block so they appear beside each other

```
<li>
   <div class="itemTitle"><a href="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/results-boardroom/expect-20-topline-growthfy16-sintex-industries_3626821.html" target="_blank">Expect 20% topline growth in FY16: Sintex Industries</a></div>
   <div class="itemDetail">
      <span class="itemDate">10/16/2015, 11:11 AM</span>
      <span class="Source">moneycontrol</span>
      <div class="itemContent"><img src="http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2015/s/samir-joshipura-200.jpg" alt="Samir Joshipura" title="Samir Joshipura" border="0" width="75" height="75" hspace="5"> Samir Joshipura Group CEO, Sintex is confident of meeting the guidance of 20 percent topline growth in FY16 and margin growth between 50-100 basis points.</div>
   </div>
</li>
```